# 'User' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make twitter clone, and here is the problem when I am trying to send a tweet.

Models

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

Form

```
class TweetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        exclude = ["user", 'date']
```

And now I am trying to add User to tweet information mannualy, but get the error: `'User' object does not support indexing`

Here is view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TweetForm(request.POST)
        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            author = form.save(commit=False)
            author.user = UserProfile.objects.get(request.user)  #HERE ASIGNING THE USER
            author.save()
```

How to corectly assign user to tweet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your `Author` model class has a foreign key to the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` you're using (the default is `auth.User`) the line:

```
author.user = UserProfile.objects.get(request.user)
```

should be:

```
author.user = request.user
```