# Django Many-to-one with Users Unique Constraint Failing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a project where I have a class called Investment. Basically, a user can can have many investments, and an investment can consist of many users. As such my models.py looks like this:

```
# Not sure if this class is relevant to my question
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=55, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Investment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    offered_fund = models.ForeignKey(OfferedFunds)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.offered_fund.fund_name.name
```

and my forms.py:

```
class InvestmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        fields = ('offered_fund','amount')
        exclude = ['user']
```

finally, my views.py:

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user
    instance.save()
```

So the way it works when deployed is the user selects an offered_fund, and enters an amount then hits submit. When I do this once, it registers and I can see it in the Django Administration page. However, the second time I try to do it (selecting the same or a different offered_fund) I get the error:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: users_investment.user_id

Any idea on how I can solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `ForeignKey` relationship which only allows one `User` object for each `Investment`.

You should be using a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) which allows more than one `User` per `Investment`.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was thinking. However now I get the error: `'User' object does not support indexing`

Comment: That's a different issue, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26021206/2532070 for the solution