# Django: 'User' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have been incurring the problem:

> 'User' object does not support indexing

ever since I changed from a ForeignKey to a ManyToManyField for to get Users:

```
user = models.ManyToManyField(User) # Was ForeignKey before
```

Here is my views.py file:

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user # The problem I'm guessing
    instance.offered_fund = default_state
    instance.save()
```

I tried to follow the instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26021206/1615532) with no success. Additionally I am using Python3 if that has anything to do with the problem. Any ideas on how I can solve this? Thanks

Comment: Did you delete the previous data?

Comment: No, but when I try I get the error: `no such table: users_investment_user` should I do an `sql flush`?

Comment: When you have a FK you only need a field with the related object's id, but when you have a M2M field, you need an extra table, that's why you gte that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
instance.user = request.user
```

Well, user is ManyToManyField, you couldn't just just assign it to model, because it's "set" of models.

Don't you want to do this one instead?

```
instance.user.add(request.user)
```

Comment: That gives me the error: `"<Investment: Investment object>" needs to have a value for field "investment" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`, citing `instance.user.add(request.user)` as the issue

Comment: You can't associate M2M object until it's been saved.

Comment: i have everything saved, [here is a  a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TxG7vfdJ), should I be saving somewhere else?

Comment: You should save your model _before_  M2M linking.

Comment: Just place line 3 after line 5

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. However it seems like for every one problem I fix another just pops up. I am getting an error: `NOT NULL constraint failed: users_investment.user_id` which seems strange. I cant imagine why Django would be mad that the field is not null?

Comment: You shuold change your field description to `user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)` to allow field be optional.

Comment: @shhdup he needs `null=True` rather, right? because `blank=True` is not for db

Comment: @doniyor null doesn't mean anything at the database level when used with a ManyToManyField. The invocation of a ManyToManyField causes the creation of an intermediate table to hold the relationship, and although Django will create a standard attribute on your model instance for your convenience, there is no actual column representing it that could be nulled. By definition there can always be zero instances of the relationship.

blank=True, though, does have an effect, forcing you to choose at least one relation.

Comment: @shhdup is right `null=True` returns a message in mu command prompt stating it has no effect on ManyToManyFields. However even after adding `blank=True` I get the same error`NOT NULL constraint failed`

Comment: @ng150716 try `./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate`

Comment: It's definitely an integrity error. Try to erase all database schema and resync it.

Comment: For the testing purpose you could just connect empty sqlite database

Comment: I did a `python manage.py flush` and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93939/discussion-between-ng150716-and-shhdup).

Answer (score 0):

First you need this line of code to add user to your objects.

```
instance.user.add(request.user)
```

instead of

```
instance.user = request.user
```

But, you also need to run some changes to convert the current foreign key user to new M2M user data.

So i would suggest following steps to do first:

1.) Make a new M2M relationship and keep the existing foreign key also.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User) 
users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

2.) Migrate DB Now.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

3.) Run following code from terminal to migrate data.

```
for obj in Model.objects.all():
    obj.users.add(obj.user)
```

4.) Delete the old user field ( Also change users to user, if you wish, but i would recommend to use as `users` to reflect plurality. Migrate again.

5.) Make the necessary changes in code like at top to add or process users instead of user.